# I have a static sub-domain for my site that holds the images/css/js and whenever I try and point the code to it....nothing workds

Tags: html, css, subdomain

I can't get anything to show up right.

This is the **head** of one of my pages:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static.wkara.com/css/menu.css"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="menu2.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home!</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static.wkara.com/css/default.css"   />

</head>
```

The sub-domain points to a folder called static that is in the root of the website.

- root

  - static (static.wkara.com points to here)

    - css

      - all the css stuff

When I link to the css stuff like this "static/css/blahh.css" it works though.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a relative URL, so you need to specify a protocal.

- Incorrect: `static.wkara.com/css/menu.css`
- Correct: `http://static.wkara.com/css/menu.css`
- Even better: `//static.wkara.com/css/menu.css` (Thanks Samus)

Some browsers may be "smart" enough to do it automatically, but I wouldn't count on it.

---

The logical reason for this is `http://wkara.com/current/page/static.wkara.com/css/menu.css` is a valid URL.  If you give a protocol (HTTP, FTP, etc.) it knows you're referring to an absolute location.

Comment: I added a note at the bottom with my guess as to "Why?"

Comment: I've heard of a trick that is to use `//` only as protocol and let the browser figure it out, not sure how reliable it is but it's what people recomment when you have both http and https.

Comment: @Samus_, yes, that's better.  I forgot about it, but I updated my answer.